# Selecting multiple elements from an array in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I would like to select from an array the four highest elements in descending order in terms of length.

I sorted the array in descending order, and picked the elements.

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: `arr.max_by(n) {|i| #condition }` in certain cases will work.

Comment: If you want to collect the first `n` objects that satisfy a condition then maybe use `each_with_object` or `with_object` with an array object and build it up until you collect `n` objects.

Comment: The thing: I want elements that are highest among all the other elements, not the ones that meet a specific condition. Would you please provide an example of how to accomplish it using `each_with_object` or `with_object`?

Comment: Then I would not recommend `each_with_object` or `with_object`. On another note be aware of behaviour when using `max_by` with duplicate elements i.e. `[9,9,8].max_by(2, &:itself) #=> [9, 9]`. And also note there is the corresponding `min_by` method too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
%w(one two three four five size seven eight).max_by(3, &:length)
=> ["seven", "eight", "three"]
```

Comment: My bad. I have re-phrased my question.

Comment: `max_by(3, &:length)` :)